# Who exactly is not going to the 2022 Beijing Winter Olympic Games because of political boycotts?

Tags: international-relations, china, sports

Various countries are reporting [political boycotts](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-59646231) of the upcoming Beijing 2022 Winter Olympics, but it's not clear to me who will not go to the Olympics as a result.

Due to COVID-19, there are strong ticket restrictions:

> Tickets will be sold exclusively to spectators residing in China's mainland, who meet the requirements of the COVID-19 countermeasures.
> <sub>[Olympics.com](https://olympics.com/en/beijing-2022/tickets), viewed 14 December 2021.</sub>

So it seems these boycotts only affect government employees from the USA, UK, Australia, Canada (and possibly other countries who decide to similarly boycott) who live in China, presumably people working at embassies in China.  However, it is possible there would ordinarily be special VIP tickets (or something similar) for politicians that I'm unaware of.

**Question**: Who exactly is not going to the 2022 Beijing Winter Olympic Games because of political boycotts?

Comment: Is it clear how ticketing will work? Who will be invited or allowed to attend? What do IOC rules say? I guess it's possible that due to COVID China could decide nobody can visit; IOC rules may say certain people can attend, but the IOC has limited powers to enforce its will.

Answer (score 3):

> So it seems these boycotts only affect government employees from the USA, UK, Australia, Canada (and possibly other countries who decide to similarly boycott) who live in China, presumably people working at embassies in China. However, it is possible there would ordinarily be special VIP tickets (or something similar) for politicians that I'm unaware of.
>
> Question: Who exactly is not going to the 2022 Beijing Winter Olympic Games because of political boycotts?

I guess there are two sides to this question. On the one hand there's the boycott side, which could prevent some officials from attending. On the other side there's the announcement that the games are closed to foreign visitors which means that regardless of a boycott they might not be allowed to visit in the first place.

I don't think it's true that there's a blanket ban on foreign visitors. Regular visits to the country may be restricted and ticket sales may be limited to Chinese residents, but that doesn't mean officials cannot (be invited to) attend. For example, the UN Secretary General says he has been invited by the International Olympic Committee (IOC). According to [Al Jazeera](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2021/12/9/un-chief-to-attend-beijing-olympics-amid-diplomatic-boycotts):

> “The secretary-general received an invitation from the International Olympic Committee to attend the opening of the Beijing Winter Games and he has accepted it,” spokesman Stephane Dujarric told reporters.

That news report doesn't say China has endorsed the invitation, but neither doers it say that China has opposed it. Such Chinese opposition has been reported with respect to the US boycott. According to [BBC News](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-59556613):

> China's Washington embassy also waded in on the announcement, calling the boycott a "grave distortion of the spirit of the Olympic Charter".
>
> "No-one would care about whether these people come or not, and it has no impact whatsoever on the Beijing 2022 Winter Olympics to be successfully held," said spokesman Liu Pengyu, quoted by Reuters.
>
> Mr Liu added that no invitation had been extended to US politicians, "so this 'diplomatic boycott simply comes out of nowhere".

That last statement makes it seem that non-Chinese residents are allowed to visit if they are invited.

To get some more insight in the process of getting to the Olympics, we can take a look at [the playbook for the Olympic and Paralympic family](https://stillmed.olympics.com/media/Documents/Olympic-Games/Beijing-2022/Playbooks/The-Playbook-RHBs-IFs-TOP-OF-PF-Press-Workforce-December-2021.pdf) which covers some government officials as well. Specifically, under the heading *Olympic and Paralympic Family* it covers the following government officials:

- *Sovereigns or Heads of State and Heads of Government*,
- *Sport Ministers of NOCs/NPCs with participating athletes*,
- *Other prominent Government officials*,
- *Heads of Diplomatic Mission with participating athletes*,
- *Staff of Sovereigns or Heads of State and Heads of Government*,
- *Mayors of next Olympic and Paralympic Games Host Cities*.

For the period up to January 3rd, the playbook mentions the requirement for a visa. It says that Beijing 2022 will help with an invitation letter and the visa application. For the period after that, the playbook describes the Pre-Valid Card as the identity document for use during the Olympics.  It says:

> Make sure you have a Pre-Valid Card (PVC), which
> will be validated to become your Olympic Identity
> and Accreditation Card (OIAC)/Paralympic Identity
> and Accreditation Card (PIAC). Your PVC will act as
> an entry document or visa waiver into China; without
> it you will need to apply for a visa...

> Air travel to Beijing* will be made possible through
> charter, temporary and commercial flights only if
> you hold Games accreditation (PVC or OIAC/PIAC)
> or a valid visa supported by a Beijing 2022 invitation
> letter.

As such, it seems to me that any of the government officials covered in the list above can apply for PVC which allows them to attend the Olympics. It's not clear to me if PVC applications have to be approved by the Chinese government separately.

---

So back to your question. I think it's a fair assumption that the government officials covered by the list above can attend the Olympics if they want to. Their own government may be able prevent them from doing so depending on their political system.

Of course the real question is whether any officials would attend the Games if not for a boycott measure by their government. That's a bit speculative because we'd have to take their word for it.

One way to find the answer would be to make a list of all the countries which are boycotting the Olympics. Then see if any of their government officials had expressed a willingness to attend before the boycott was announced by their government. If it later turns out that such officials don't attend the Olympics, then we can reasonably say that the boycott has prevented them from going.

In my search, I haven't found any such a government official (intending to go, but prevented by the boycott). That doesn't mean there are none. If were to guess, I'd focus on Sport ministers who have casually expressed an intention to attend the Olympics (for example to support one of their country's athletes). That wouldn't be a big announcement necessarily so those could be hard to find.

Of course for individual politicians it's easy to give another reason for not attending. That way they don't unnecessarily offend China but it allows them to stay away nonetheless. For example, the Dutch King who is also an [IOC member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_members_of_the_International_Olympic_Committee#Current_members) has expressed his intention not to attend because of the pandemic. He made the same decision with the Tokyo Olympics. As [stated by the Minister of Foreign Affairs](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=nl&tl=en&u=https://www.rtlnieuws.nl/nieuws/nederland/artikel/5272489/coronavirus-willem-alexander-china-olympische-spelen), it would be (translated) *'a strange portrayal if one fan can attend when thousands of others cannot'*.

So that shows it's quite hard to say whether a politician who could otherwise apply to attend doesn't do so for the boycott reason or for some other reason.